# What is the best way to make persistent in-app notifications with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I learned how to use push notifications at Firebase. It works. As the next step, I want to add persistent in-app notifications, similar to Stackoverflow, Facebook, Instagram, etc

Currently we're using at Firestore and Real-Time database.

We have several use cases:

1. Users' content is viewed
2. Users receive a message from another user
3. Some system update about a new feature

Where should we keep these notification messages? Should it be in the same place where all original messages are stored? Or should each user have notification collections? Or are there some other ways to solve it?

[image]

I found a lot of stuff about push notifications, but I can't find anything how to handle regular persistent notifications.

Comment: did you manage to come up with a solution? What was the best solution?

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte I'm not sure if that is the best solution, but I used Firestore to store notifications. I created "notification" collection and added all notifications per user there.